# ¿Donde hacer la carga de datos en los fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-room

actualmente estoy desarrollando una app de control de indicadores, he integrados gráficos y listas de indicadores, uso Room para almacenar datos, el flujo de la aplicación es el siguiente.

**Primera carga:** Verifico en el MainActivity las preferencias y si es la primera carga, redirijo a una actividad para una carga de datos inicial.

**Resto de cargas:** Valido las preferencias y cargo los fragment de la aplicación *(BottomNavigationView)*.

**Fragment por defecto:** Cuando llego al fragment por defecto (Home), inflo la vista en *onCreateView* y los datos en *onViewCreated* con **GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)** ya que las funciones DAO son suspend, inicialmente todo va fluido.

**Registro de datos:** En un *Toolbar* tengo un menú para registrar datos, y cuando finaliza vuelve al fragment *Home* con la vista y datos actualizados, todo es instantáneo, pero en un fragment secundario cargo un gráfico lineal con MPAndroidChart, y ahí es donde me ha surgido la duda.

***¿Desde donde es más optimo la carga de datos para fragment? (no se usar livedata ni viewmodel):***

Comment: Recuerda revisar [ask], recuerda "Necesita ser más específica
Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema."

Comment: Disculpa, no quería generar dudas de lo que necesito, ya lo he simplificado en una sola.

Comment: Creo que deberías empezar a mirar arquitectura de software, por ejemmplo, el libro Clean Architecture.  Con él aprenderás cómo gestionar este problema que es tener unos datos centralizados y que las pantallas puedan acceder a ellos.  Por ejemplo, pasando la id del dato y que la pantalla lo cargue: UI -> llama al Presenter/ViewModel -> Que llama al Dominio (UseCase / Entities) -> Que llama al Repositorio (Hace flujos de datos con varias Fuentes de datos: Network, Database, etc.) y llama a la Base de Datos (Room en tu caso)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero remitiendome a la pregunta, ¿en qué evento es más factible la carga de datos?

Comment: Livedata es para escuchar como un listener, cada cambio se ejecutara la funcion callback. View model es para persistir datos a cambios de configuraciones cuando se recree el activity, por ej al cambiar de orientacion , al recibir una llamada. El fragment tiene lifecycle tambien , la mayoria carga en oncreate view.